# Using Dropzone to upload files to Dropbox via upload_sessions

Tags: dropbox-api, dropzone.js

We currently have a simple form that uses Dropzone to allow file uploads to the server. THis works well.

We are also using another instance of Dropzone to upload files directly to Dropbox. Using Dropbox's get_temp_upload_link endpoint we dynamically generate a folder name and path and pass the link to Dropzone's URL parameter. However, this endpoint has a file limit on it and we can't upload chunks of the file to it as it wont be rebuilt at the other end.

So Im guessing we need to use Dropbox's upload_session_start, upload_session_append and upload_session_finish endpoints to chunk the upload to Dropbox.

I have 2 questions.

1. Do I have to use Dropzone chunking to upload parts of the file at a time? Or can I just upload the whole file to the browser before beign chunked up to Dropzone.
2. Is there a way to hide the access token from the client, or is there a way to dynamically generate an access Token for Dropbox that I can then revoke after the upload has finished.

Any questions let me know and ill clarify.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Discuss-Dropbox-Developer-API/Uploading-large-files-directly-from-web-application/m-p/405449#M1073 ]